# To withdraw volunteering, is it unvolunteer or un-volunteer?

Tags: grammar, hyphenation

I read rules for hyphenating and I think it said an adjective proceeding a verb needs a hyphen. True?

Comment: as in your title - to withdraw

Comment: I would say neither. To *withdraw* ***volunteering*** is to withdraw the ability for anybody to volunteer. In other words, the act of volunteering, in general, is no longer possible. It's the same thing as saying *eating at meetings is no longer allowed*. So, your question is confusing two different things. To withdraw **volunteering** might be thought of as ***unvolunteering*** or ***un-volunteering*** but never as *unvolunteer* or *un-volunteer*.

Comment: The rule you mention in the body doesn’t seem relevant, because “un” is not an adjective.

Comment: How do you wish to treat someone who ***withdraws*** (the right word here IMO).  You could could try guilting them into changing their mind:  “***Renege***”

Comment: to stop volunteering.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Is it a word?**

The word "unvolunteer" isn't standard: it [doesn't appear](https://www.onelook.com/?w=unvolunteer&ls=a) in any of the main online dictionaries. As there's always a risk that a novel word will be misunderstood, in formal communication it would therefore be best to say "I'd like to withdraw my offer to volunteer", "Please remove me from the volunteer list", or simply "I don't want to volunteer any more." But in an informal situation, provided there's adequate context, *unvolunteer* will most likely be understood as intended, i.e. *withdraw from volunteering*.

However, be aware that the *adjective* ["unvolunteered"](https://www.yourdictionary.com/unvolunteered) does **not** mean "withdrew from volunteering". Instead, it means "not volunteered". For example, a confession obtained under torture could be described as an unvolunteered confession. This word too is non-standard, as there's a perfectly good word that already serves the purpose: [involuntary](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/involuntary).

**Should I hyphenate it?**

> I read rules for hyphenating and I think it said an adjective
>   proceeding a verb needs a hyphen. True?

The rule for creating a compound adjective using an adjective (or adverb), hyphen and past participle (e.g. *hard-earned*, *short-lived*, *deep-seated*, *open-ended*, *well-argued*, etc) doesn't apply to *unvolunteer* because (a) *un-* is a prefix, not an adjective, and (b) *volunteer* is not a participle.

Modern practice is to eschew hyphens and diacritics whenever possible. With a *prefix*, we generally hyphenate if adding the prefix (a) results in consecutive vowels that are usually pronounced as a monosyllable, *and* (b) it would therefore be confusing without the hyphen. Thus we would write *re-edit* rather than *reedit* and *co-opt* rather than *coopt*, but modern practice is not to hyphenate words like *reorder* or *reinvent*. [We'll leave aside the debate about *cooperation*!]

If you do intend to write the word *unvolunteer*, it's not strictly incorrect to insert a hyphen, but it's unnecessary and would be inconsistent with modern practice.

Comment: "Modern practice" uses rather a broad brush.

Comment: @TRomano Do you disagree with the practice or with the observation?

Comment: I take issue with the observation in the sense that 'modern practice' is not monolithic.

Comment: @TRomano Can you suggest an amendment that is both accurate and non-monolithic?

Answer (score 1):

When a speaker senses that a word doesn't *really* exist but can be formed by analogy with other words, especially words formed by tacking a prefix onto a verb, the speaker will place extra emphasis on the first syllable:

> Now that  *she* is going to be heading the committee, I wish I could **un**-volunteer.

The syllable receiving heavy emphasis is often separated from the rest of the word with a slightly longer micro-pause than that syllable would have if the word it was used in was "canonical"; if you wish to reflect that pause (or the underlying fact that causes it) on the page, you'd use a hyphen.

Comment: are you saying that it is OK to use "un-volunteer"? I'm putting as the text of a button on a web page which to me means it's an action.

Comment: Your question asks about the "rules for hyphenating".  I don't give free advice about website UI design and labels for buttons. :)

Comment: I was looking for free advice on how to express it shortly. It's good to have rules for what you give free advice on.

Comment: I gave you a rule. You simply did not recognize it as being a rule.